# Vimeo API PHP Too many API requests

Tags: php, vimeo-api

I'm developing a part of my project doing a call to Vimeo API to get the "views" for videos but I'm facing constantly the same error

> [error] => Too many API requests. Wait an hour or so, then try again

I think that I'm doing well the auth process but for sure I'm missing something

```
$client_id='123456';
$client_identifier='123456';        
$client_secret='123456';
$access_token = '123456';
$scope = "public";

$lib = new Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret);

$lib->setToken($access_token);

$video_details = $lib->request('/videos/'.$video_id, ['per_page' => 2], 'GET');
```

but after few test I get that error

> [error_code] => 9003

someone know the better practical way to avoid that issue? actually this is frustrated.

thanks!

Comment: That error message has nothing to do with the Auth. You've seem to have been making more requests to their API within one hour than they permit. Cache the result for a bit so you don't need to hit their API on every single request.

Comment: https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/rate-limiting

Comment: thanks for your comment, I think that I doing by this 
 
$video_details = $vimeo->request('/videos/'.$video_id, ['per_page' => 2], 'GET'); 
             
$video_stats = $video_details["body"]["stats"];  
wp_cache_set('video_stats', $video_stats );